# regression OLS in python

Tags: python, regression, least-squares

I have some questions about multiple regression models in python:

1. Why is it necessary to apply a “dummy intercept” vector of ones to start for the Least Square method (OLS)? (I am refering to the use of X = sm.add_constant(X). I know that the Least square method is a system of derivatives equal to zero. Is it computed with some iterative method that make a “dummy intercept” necessary? Where can I find some informative material about the detail of the algorithm est = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()?
2. As far as I understood, scale.fit_transform produce a normalization of the data. Usually a normalization do not produce value higher than 1. Why, once scaled I see value that exceed 1?
3. Where  is it possible to find a official documentation about python functions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Python is open source you can investigate into the library if you want to

Comment: What do you mean as 'investigate into the library'? Is there a way to see the code of the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In the OLS the function you are trying to fit is :
   y=ax1+ax2+ax3+c. if you don't use c term, your line will always pass through the origin. Hence to give more degrees of freedom to your line which can be offset by c from your origin you need c .

You can fit a line without constant term and you will get set of coefficients (dummy intercept is not necessary for iterative computation), but that might not be the best possible straight line which minimises the least square.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But why the starting c term has to be an array of 1. Shouldn't this force the passage from 1? If the OLS corresponds to the least square method, why the needs of imposing the passage from 1 ?

Comment: consider the  regression equation given by a1x1+a2x2+a3x3+a4x4+a5x5+a6. you can think of a6 as a6*x6 where x6 is always 1.  Thus an array of 1 is dummy for additional feature (Additional x) with constant value of x.

Comment: So with X = sm.add_constant(X), you are not adding a constant a6 but x6 which is an array of one, isnt it?

Comment: yes.  You are adding a constant x6. a6 would get computed by iteratively reducing error function.